# .htaccess RewriteRule for multiple pages

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've done RewriteRule for index page in my website.

Here is the code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)/?$ /index.php?origin=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]+)/?$ /index.php?origin=$1&gender=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]+)/?$ /index.php?origin=$1&gender=$2&type=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]+)/?$ /index.php?origin=$1&gender=$2&type=$3&page=$4
</IfModule>
```

and the url is looks like

```
http://babynames.agurchand.com/scottish/male/pythagorean
```

It's a single page website, so everything is working fine so far. 
Then i wanted to add one more page on my website and i have added too. file name is 'namemeaning.php'.

I've added the below code in addition of the htaccess pasted, at the bottom. But It doesn't seem to be working.

```
RewriteRule ^/namemeaning/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)/?$ /namemeaning/namemeaning.php?name=$1
```

I've tried with the below url, but I'm still being referred to the index page only.

```
http://babynames.agurchand.com/namemeaning/abasi
```

Can anyone give me a solution for this please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being forwarded to the index page because your regular expression for the index page fits your request. You're being sent to index.php?origin=namemeaning&gender=abasi

```
http://babynames.agurchand.com/namemeaning/abasi
'namemeaning' fits the rule ([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)
'abasi' fits the rule ([a-zA-Z0-9+\-]+)
```

A simple fix would be adding the line

```
RewriteRule ^/namemeaning/([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)/?$ /namemeaning/namemeaning.php?name=$1
```

above the line

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+\-\(\)]+)/?$ /index.php?origin=$1
```

You should remember to always place the most specific RewriteRule(s) above those that are more general.

For more information about regular expressions, I can advice you [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

The rewruite rules are checked sequentially from top to bottom, and all rules matched are applied in that order. Double check that none of your rules match before the desired one.
Good Tool for that purpose is http://www.regextester.com/